# Accessing variables/functions from another class

Tags: c++, class

I'm making a card game and I have a few classes. 
I have a Hand class, a Player Class, a "Column" class (where the cards are placed on the screen after the hand) and I need each class to have access to the other classes' variables.

```
class Hand
{
private:
    int **Hx,Hy;** //Hand X, Hand Y
    int HAmount;//Amount of cards in Hand
    int HOwner; //Player 1/2
    int Limit; //Limit of cards in Hand
    int HContents[8]; //Card Position in 54 card deck NOT card value.
    bool Removed;
public:
    Hand();
    void Lim();
    void Get_Card();
    void Show();
    void Set_Values(int y, int Own);
};
```

Then in another class I need to have access to some of the variables above.

```
void Card::show()
{
    if((apply == true)
    {
        if((Track == true)&&(SelNum == TNum)&&(TOwner == COwner))
        {
            ScnPos = TAmount;
            x = Tx;
            y = Ty + ScnPos*10;
        }
        if((Hand == true)&&(**HOwner** == COwner))
        {

            x = **Hx** + ScnPos*45;
            y = **Hy;**
        }
        apply_surface(x,y,Cards,Screen,&Clip[Pos]);
    }
}
```

I've tried using class friendship and other methods but I can't make it work.
(obviously I have more variables which need this same treatment)
(ignore any errors in my code)

Answer (score 2):

The errors in your code are the real problem here. there is no reason that a `Card` will access a `Hand`'s private member. this is design error, and your other problems are just trying to tell you that.

Comment: i agree. no reason a card needs to know anything about a hand. Whatever logic is involved in making all of the cards in a hand interact should be in the hand class, and that should call methods on that card class that interact with other cards.

class friendship not necessary here, and usually isn't necessary in any well designed program.

Comment: @Elazar _Thanks, I thought class friendship was kind of incorrect.. Obviously my program is far from "well designed" at this point then._

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should make `getters` and `setters` for your variables. E.g.:

```
class Test {
    private: int a;
    public: int GetA() {
       return this->a;
    }
    void SetA(int a) {
       this->a = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: no need to reference this. it's implied. you only need this when you need to reference the calling object itself, and not one of its members. like return *this

Comment: in the example you cited, the passed in a should just not be called a.

Comment: @bdwain - in this case he needs to; `this->a` is the `a` of the instance against which the function executes, and `a` is the argument passed in. And that, @Ivan, should show you why I ughed: because this is confusing code. Imagine how easily someone could subtly break this code by simply searching and replacing instances of `"this->"` with `""`.

Comment: yea i read that right after and realized that the naming was bad.